# bypass interceptor in stripes bean class

Tags: java, stripes, intercept

I have created a interceptor for my application. I am using stripes framework.
This interceptor intercept all reuqest from browser. I want one of bean class to bypass this interceptor.

```
@Intercepts(LifecycleStage.BindingAndValidation)
public class XssInterceptor implements Interceptor
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code inside of your intercept method:

```
@Override
public Resolution intercept(ExecutionContext context) throws Exception {
    if (!(context.getActionBean() instanceof BypassedActionBean)) {
        // XSS filtering
    }
    return context.proceed();
}
```